# Method returns null when accessing getter

Tags: java

I have been trying to print the player name (using `Scanner`) to the screen, but it keeps giving me `null` instead of what the person types.

As you can see below, `playerOneName` is being displayed correctly when using the `playerName()` method, but as soon as I try to use the `startingHouse()` method, it displays `null`.

**Update: Added solution:**

Had to add the following code in the class Player_Information:

```
    public Player_Information(){
    super();
    playerName();
    }
```

**First class:**

```
public class Player_Information {

    Scanner inputName = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String playerOneName;

    void playerName() {
        System.out.print("What is your name? - ");
        playerOneName = inputName.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Greetings " + playerOneName + "!\n");
    }

    public String getPlayerOneName() {
        return playerOneName;
    }

    public void setPlayerOneName(String playerOneName) {
        this.playerOneName = playerOneName;
    }
}
```

**Second class:**

```
public class Locations {

    Player_Information plIn = new Player_Information();

    public void startingHouse() {
        System.out.println(plIn.getPlayerOneName() + ": Agh.. What happened..");
    }
}
```

I am referring to `getPlayerOneName()` in the `Player_Information` class, so why is it returning `null`?

**Thank you :)**

Comment: What did you expect it to return? and why? You haven't even initialized the field.

Comment: Because `playerOneName` is `null`. You probably mean to call `playerName()` first.

Comment: Side note: An object shouldn't *initiate user interaction* in order to get its necessary value.  Require the value on the constructor itself.  Then the application should control the user interaction and supply the value when constructing the object.  The way you're currently doing it introduces unnecessary external dependencies on the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting null because you never initialize playerOneName. This String gets initialized to the value of `inputName.nextLine();` in the PlayerName() method. In order to have a value when you use the getPlayerOneName() method, the variable playerOneName must first be initialized. In your program, the method PlayerName() initializes the variable, so call that method first.

```
public class Locations {

    Player_Information plIn = new Player_Information();

    public void startingHouse() {
        plIn.PlayerName(); // call this first to initialize playerOneName;
        System.out.println(plIn.getPlayerOneName() + ": Agh.. What happened..");
    }
}
```

A far better way to handle this error would be to add a constructor to your Player_Information class where the variable could be initialized. Something along the lines of the code below would do...

```
/*add this to your Player_Information class at the beginning */
public Player_Information(){
    super();
    //one option is to set a value to playerOneName here...
    playerOneName = "set whatever string value you want to use here";
    //or...call PlayerName() here instead.
    PlayerName();
}
```

Comment: One quick question: When I add
`public Player_Information() { playerName(); } `
it **1)** Runs the code when I launch the program (it is supposed to run when I input 1 in a Menu I have created). **2)** It runs the same code twice?). How can I fix those issues?

Thank you for your answer! ♥

Comment: I am confused on your first point, but on the second, I am guessing the code runs twice because you are call playerName() somewhere outside of the constructor in your code. Then when you say Player_Information plIn = new Player_Information(); the playerName() method is called a second time as it is part of the constructor. If you are calling PlayerName() anywhere outside of your constructor you should remove it.

Comment: I removed `Player_Information plIn = new Player_Information();` from another class, and now it seems to be working absolutely fine! Thank you for a nice and detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this method first `playerName()` as so:

```
plIn.playerName();//this will prompt for input
System.out.println(plIn.getPlayerOneName() + ": Agh.. What happened..");
```

However, this whole design seems odd.  I would recommend separating your Scanner from your `Player_Information` class.  And add a setter for `Player_Information`.

Comment: Oh! So I need to add the plIn.playerName(); to the method which is using it? I added it to a new class called Progress, and called it from there. I switched it to the startingHouse() and it seems to be working now! :)

Answer (score 0):

This line `Player_Information plIn = new Player_Information();` calls the default constructor of `Player_Information` (because you did not define one), and you never initialized your `playerOneName` field (because you didn't call your `playerName()` method. You might define a constructor like this

```
public Player_Information() {
  super();
  playerName(); // <-- will invoke the function on instantiation.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the object

Player_Information plIn = new Player_Information();

The attribute playerOneName is null at that time so you need to call the method playerName to set the attribute value.